# How can I check if the difference between two times is grater then 8.30 or not?

Tags: sql, plsql

```
SELECT to_char(TO_CHAR(T1_TO_TIME,'HH:MI')-TO_CHAR(T1_FR_TIME,'HH:MI') )
FROM Table1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
8.5 hours / 24 hours = 0.3541666 of a day.

In Oracle, one way to do it.

select 
  case
    when (to_date('6-4-2015 17:10','dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi')
         -to_date('6-4-2015 8:45','dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi'))
         > 0.3541666 then
      'More than 8.30 hours'
    else
      'Less than 8.30 hours'
  end 
from dual
```